# Show install native app prompt in Flutter PWA

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps

What is the best way to show a prompt to install the native app on a Flutter PWA?

I found this guide https://developer.chrome.com/blog/app-install-banners-native/ but I am not sure where the Javascript should go or if this needs to be coded somehow in Flutter code.

I also thought of maybe building a dialog myself, but I don't find an easy way to generate a persisten dialog over the whole app that can be dismissed by the user

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in both Javascript and Flutter. The [Native App Install Prompt](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/app-install-banners-native/) link provides criterias which must be met and instructions how to prompt.

Here is one way to accomplish it in Flutter.

```
BeforeInstallPrompt(
  child: HomeScreen(),
),
```

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BeforeInstallPrompt extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const BeforeInstallPrompt({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _BeforeInstallPrompt();
}

class _BeforeInstallPrompt extends State<BeforeInstallPrompt> {
  BeforeInstallPromptEvent? deferredPrompt;

  @override
  void initState() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setState(() {
        deferredPrompt = e as BeforeInstallPromptEvent;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      widget.child,
      if (deferredPrompt != null)
        Positioned(
          left: 8,
          bottom: 8,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await _showPrompt();
            },
            child: const Text('Install'),
          ),
        )
    ]);
  }

  _showPrompt() async {
    await deferredPrompt?.prompt();
    await deferredPrompt?.userChoice;
    setState(() {
      deferredPrompt = null;
    });
  }
}
```